# Why does django post stops working over https? It's working over http

Tags: django, ssl, https

So,

When I'm trying to change django production server from http to https, by using these settings:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'SRSession'
```

The POST requests from the browser just stops working(not even the login from the admin panel), but the get requests are working fine and the site have a valid ssl ceritifcate, I'm using OpenLiteSpeed

[image: how it looks on Chrome network tab]

This is how the request looks in chrome network tab and it goes on like this until I get a timeout error.

If I use HTTP on the production server to get the cookies then I use HTTPs the GET request are working fine.

Comment: pending usually occurs when you have an invalid ssl certificate issue. I would start looking there first.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this lead me to do some research about the ssl certificate, it wasn't about that, but it was resolved by running this: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y I still have no idea what the problem was...